# Web browser control WP8 leaking/using too much RAM?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, browser, webbrowser-control, ram

I have been developing for WP7 for a while now and have been using the webbrowser control to manage some of the webpages. I was able to have 8 web browser controls open, and everything was running smoothly and didn't crash at all in WP7.

I tried to recreate (not port) the same application to WP8, and all of a sudden it keeps crashing on 1 or 2 webbrowser controls. I used the memory tracker and saw that one web browser control was using 35-55mb of RAM. Does anyone know why the WP8 web browser control is so different from the WP7 control, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the repro steps (e.g. what pages you're loading, how you're making the calls) as well as memory profiling results (since you mentioned that you analyzed those).

Comment: well, for example i try to load simple websites on the wp8 web browser control like mobile google and it only uses like 15-10 mb of ram, however when i try to load a website like the verge it the ram usage goes to 50-60 mb and then the app crashes. This never happened in the wp7 browser control.